# Move site collection

Tags: sharepoint

is it possible to move a site collection from one web application to another ?

I currently have a site collection developped in a web application called ABC.
We need to transfer this site collection to another web application called DEF.

These 2 web apps are on the same MOSS server. Does stdadm can do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can use STSADM -o backup and then restore it to the other one.

Comment: If you are moving a site collection based on the Publishing Template, you will first need to create a temporary Publishing site collection on the destination before restoring your backed up site collection.  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use stsadm -o export and stsadm -o import

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint sites are not actually moved from one location or server to another; rather, they are backed up to a file or exported to a file, and then the content or site is re-created from the backup file or imported from file.

stsadm -export
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262759.aspx

stsadm -backup
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441.aspx